# double approach of targetting function and elements in my js lib problem

Tags: javascript, function, class

I'm building my little lib js.

my intent is to have both possibilities in this way:

```
//this:

core.find(".myclass").myAction (actor);

var target = core.target (".myclassname");
core.myAction (target, actor);

//or:

core.find(".myclass").myAction (actor);

var target = core.find(".myclassname");
core.myAction (target, actor);

//so, return the finded for core and gearcore, but
//I can not and I do not think it's feasible (is it?)


//this isn't a good solution... thanks.
//var target = core.find(".myclassname");
//target .myAction (target, actor);
```

anyway... the first is chained, the second part from the first class and generates the action through a parameter.

yes, I already know that I can create a copy of the functions, but it's disgusting ... and copy the target how can I solve it?

here it's about joining the two "find" or putting the two return or joining the two return or something else or maybe something similar.

for convenience: [lib in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaLg4f5t/3/) else...

LIB:
**note 1:the two eval functions are just a demo to get an answer. the complete lib contains more and I need to assign the target in both ways**

```
    class coregears {

    constructor(gear) {
        this.gear = gear;
    }

    actor(target, fname) {
        alert("inside actor");
        let t_, f_;
        (1 == arguments.length) ? (t_ = this.gear, f_ = target) : (t_ = target, f_ = fname);
        t_.forEach((looped) => {  eval(f_)(looped); return this.gear});
    }

}
class Core {


    // return for core.function(target,actor);
    target(subject)
    {

        let name;
        var finded;

        if (subject.startsWith(".")) {
            name = subject.split(".")[1];
            finded = [...document.getElementsByClassName(name)];
        }
        if (subject.match(/\B\#\w\w+\b/g)) {
            name = subject.replace(/#(\S*)/g, 'ID_$1').split("ID_")[1];
            finded = [...document.querySelectorAll("#" + name)];
        }
        if (subject.startsWith("[")) {
            finded = [...document.querySelectorAll(subject)];
        }

        return finded;

    }

        // return for core.find(target).function(actor);
    find(subject){
        let name;

        if (subject.startsWith(".")) {
            name = subject.split(".")[1];
            find = [...document.getElementsByClassName(name)];
        }
        if (subject.match(/\B\#\w\w+\b/g)) {
            name = subject.replace(/#(\S*)/g, 'ID_$1').split("ID_")[1];
            find = [...document.querySelectorAll("#" + name)];
        }
        if (subject.startsWith("[")) {
            find = [...document.querySelectorAll(subject)];
        }
        return new coregears(find);
    } 

}
const core = new Core();
```

SCRIPT:

```
  //chain
  core.find(".test_Y").actor(myactor_1);
  function myactor_1(looped) {
      alert("actor_1");
      looped.style = "font-weight: bold; color: magenta;";
  };


  //direct
  var mytarget = core.target(".test_X");
  core.actor(mytarget,myactor_2);
  function myactor_2(looped) {
      alert("actor_2");
      looped.style = "font-weight: bold; color: green;";
  };
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="test_X">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
  <div class="test_X">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
  <div class="test_X">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
  <div class="test_Y">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
  <div class="test_Y">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
  <div class="test_Y">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
```

Idea?

update: I replaced the eval with f_.call(this,looped); thank you @Shilly.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want `var target = core.target (". myclassname");
core.myAction (target, actor);` instead of `var target = core.target (". myclassname");target.myAction (target,);` which would make more sense? It comes down to counting parameters again. If myAction gets 1 parameter, the target is the same instance, else the target is the 1st parameter. But then I would switch the parameter order around so actor is always the first parameter.

Comment: ps: querySelectorAll is pretty efficient these days. So you might not even save time by detecting if you can use getByClassName. And ids are always unique, so you can use getElementById or querySelector. Also keep in mind getByClassName returns a live nodelist while querySelector does not. That might matter when you make changes to those elements in a loop.

Comment: pps: eval() can be replaced by function.apply() as well. Don't eval unless absolutely needed, since as written, that single use of eval() is easily abused.

Comment: function.apply () I did not know it, or at least I did not know I could pass the name of a function this way. Thanks, now I study it.

Comment: as regards the "chain / direct" mode: I am aware that I can repeat the target but excluding it is really horrible I need both direct and indirect for some functions in the core.
so I have to consider it in both parts.

it is also to say that it is useless, even just as a mental approach, to execute core.find (At random it does not matter). (target, actor).

Comment: ps. to be clear the eval are two demo functions, the lib is bigger! : D

Comment: @Shilly I replaced the eval with f_.call(this,looped); thank you